# Reverse string, but not integers

Tags: python-3.x

Interview question: reverse a string, but only reverse alpha characters. Integers should keep their original position.

input:  "abc12de"
output: "edc12ba"

input:  "abcde79"
output: "edcba79"

input:  "123ab456"
output: "123ba456"

Below is my half working code.

```
def reverse_string(string):
    acc = ""
    l = []
    l.extend(string)
    for char in l:
        if char >= 0 and char <= 9:
            pass
        else:
            acc = char + acc

    return acc


print(reverse_string("abc12de"))
```

Comment: ""input: "abc12de" output: "edc12ba"": is this a typo? should it be: "ed12cba"?

Comment: @xibalba1 yes you are correct. good eyes

Comment: @Stringer is that correct? I thought the numbers where supposed to stay at the same index?! `edc12ba` -> `ed12cba` moves the numbers.

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes your assumption is correct

Comment: @Stringer Did you find any of the answers helpful?

Comment: Yes, I ended up using @MarkMeyer solution

Answer (score 3):

One strategy might be to walk pointers from both ends skipping numbers. When you find two non-numbers, swap. Stop when the pointers meet. You just need to watch out for edge cases that can occur when the string is all numbers/letters:

```
def rev(st):
    s = list(st)
    i = 0
    j = len(s)-1

    while i < j:  
        while (i < len(s) and s[i].isdigit() ):
            i += 1
        while (j >=0 and s[j]. isdigit()):
            j -= 1
        if i < j:
            s[j], s[i] = s[i], s[j]
        i += 1
        j -= 1

    return ''.join(s)

print(rev('123ab456'))
print(rev('abc12de'))
print(rev('abcde79'))
print(rev('1234'))
print(rev('abcd'))
```

**result**

> 123ba456
>   edc12ba
>   edcba79
>   1234
>   dcba

An alternative that's (maybe) a little less efficient, but easier to read would be to make a generator of all the letters in reverse order, then step through the string taking the `next()` letter from the generator for alphas or the current character if it's a number:

```
def rev(string):
    reversed_letters = (s for s in string[::-1] if s.isalpha())
    news = ''
    for s in string:
        if s.isalpha():
            news+= next(reversed_letters)
        else:
            news += s
    return news
```

Comment: should be isdigit(), not isnumeric()

Comment: @Stringer, I wish I could say I was trying to watch out for unicode fractions, but it was just a mistake. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: An alternative for the generator: `reversed_letters = filter(str.isalpha, reversed(string))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse_string(string):
    num_char_pos = []
    out_s = ""
    for i, ch in enumerate(string):
        if not ch.isalpha():
            num_char_pos.append((ch, i))
        else:
            out_s += ch
    out_s = out_s[::-1]
    for numchar in num_char_pos:
        out_s = out_s[:numchar[1]] + numchar[0]  + out_s[numchar[1]:]
    return out_s
```

1. Loop through the characters of the string, checking if they are alphabetic.
2. If true, add them to new out string, otherwise add the character and
   its position (as a tuple) to a list of numeric characters.
3. Reverse the alphabetic only string.
4. Loop over the numerics list and insert them into the new string in their original position.

**Tests:**

```
# tests:
in_out = [["abc12de", "edc12ba"]
,["abcde79", "edcba79"]
,["123ab456", "123ba456"]]

for m in in_out:
    print("in:", m[0], "expected out:", m[1], "actual out:", reverse_string(m[0]), "passes?:", m[1] == reverse_string(m[0]))
```

**Results:**

> in: abc12de expected out: edc12ba actual out: edc12ba passes?: True
>   in: abcde79 expected out: edcba79 actual out: edcba79 passes?: True
>   in: 123ab456 expected out: 123ba456 actual out: 123ba456 passes?: True

Answer (score 0):

This is the first idea that came to mind:

```
>>> def reverse_non_digits(text):
    array = list(text)
    other = [index for index, value in enumerate(array) if not value.isdecimal()]
    for a, b in zip(other, reversed(other)):
        if a >= b:
            break
        array[a], array[b] = array[b], array[a]
    return ''.join(array)

>>> reverse_non_digits('abc12de')
'edc12ba'
>>> reverse_non_digits('abcde79')
'edcba79'
>>> reverse_non_digits('123ab456')
'123ba456'
>>>
```

The next version was inspired by [Mark Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623)'s [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56297425/216356):

```
>>> def reverse_non_decimal(text):
    array, start, stop = list(text), 0, len(text) - 1
    while True:
        while start < stop and array[start].isdecimal():
            start += 1
        while start < stop and array[stop].isdecimal():
            stop -= 1
        if start >= stop:
            break
        array[start], array[stop] = array[stop], array[start]
        start, stop = start + 1, stop - 1
    return ''.join(array)

>>> reverse_non_decimal('abc12de')
'edc12ba'
>>> reverse_non_decimal('abcde79')
'edcba79'
>>> reverse_non_decimal('123ab456')
'123ba456'
>>>
```

The question one might ask is "Which one is better?" If speed is any measure of what is best, then the following numbers may be of interest to you:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('reverse_non_digits("abc123def")',
                  'from __main__ import reverse_non_digits')
2.7516707000004317
>>> timeit.timeit('reverse_non_decimal("abc123def")',
                  'from __main__ import reverse_non_decimal')
2.3575149000007514
>>>
```

Compare these results to the timing of the `rev` function in [Mark Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56297425/216356):

```
>>> def rev(st):
    s = list(st)
    i = 0
    j = len(s)-1

    while i < j:  
        while (i < len(s) and s[i].isnumeric() ):
            i += 1
        while (j >=0 and s[j].isnumeric()):
            j -= 1
        if i < j:
            s[j], s[i] = s[i], s[j]
        i += 1
        j -= 1

    return ''.join(s)

>>> timeit.timeit('rev("abc123def")',
                  'from __main__ import rev')
3.657291699999405
>>>
```

Of the three functions, it appears that `reverse_non_decimal` is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.split`:

```
import re

def reverse_string(string):
    a = re.split(r'(\D)', string)
    a[1::2] = a[-2::-2]
    return ''.join(a)
```

For example for input `'abc12de'`, splitting gives `['', 'a', '', 'b', '', 'c', '12', 'd', '', 'e', '']`. At `[1::2]` we have all the non-integer characters. Reverse them, then just join back together.