# Reverse just the alpha from mix of alphanumeric string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have been given a string like "test1982pop6005python" and I should generate the output by reversing just the alpha and numeric value should stays as is:
I tried using:

```
 def rev(string):
    reversed_letters = (s for s in string[::-1] if s.isalpha())

    new = ''
    for s in string:
        if s.isalpha():
            new += next(reversed_letters)
        else:
            new += s

    return new


s = "test1982pop6005python"
print(rev(s))
```

The output using this is `nohtyp1982pop6005tset`. However, desired output should be `tset1982pop6005nohtyp`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should reverse them word for word; first test, then pop, then python in this case.

Comment: Why did you even write that code? You clearly knew what you were doing and must've known that it doesn't do what you want. Or did you just plagiarize that from somewhere, maybe from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56297425/12671057)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to split the groups and the reverse the ones you want:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = 'test1982pop6005python'

groups = groupby(s, str.isalpha)

''.join(''.join(reversed(list(s))) 
        if isalpha else ''.join(s)  
        for isalpha, s in groups)

# tset1982pop6005nohtyp
```

Comment: Or with just one inner join: `''.join(list(s)[::(-1)**isalpha])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions as well:

```
def rev(string):
    import re
    regex = re.compile(r'(\d+|\s+)')
    l=regex.split("test1982pop6005python")   # this will split chracters and numbers separately
    return ''.join(x[::-1] if x.isalpha() else x for x in l)

s = "test1982pop6005python"
print(rev(s))

#output
tset1982pop6005nohtyp
```